# HTML: Get value from text fields and email them

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create input fields. When someone clicks the "Submit" button I want the values (if they are valid) to be emailed to myself. I am having trouble even making sure they are valid. Below is my code

```
<form action="tryjs_submitpage.htm" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name*:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Name">
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email Address*:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-group">
         <label for="company">Company:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message*:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("Email").value.indexOf("@");
    var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    submitOK = "true";

    if (name.length == 0) {
        alert("You must enter your name");
        submitOK = "false";
    } 

    if (email == -1) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail!");
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (message.length == 0) {
        alert("You must enter a message");
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (submitOK == "false") {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I modified the script from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value_formval), but when I click submit it says `tryjs_submitpage.htm` doesn't exist. Obviously this is an issue, but I can't seem to find `tryjs_submitpage.htm` anywhere to get it to work. Further I wanted to know if there was a way to trigger an email send with the appropriate information to my personal email. Thanks for the help!

Comment: remove action="tryjs_submitpage.htm" from form tag

Comment: your action should on the page where you fill up the form

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your code,

parameter document.getElementById is element id :

change code :

```
var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("Email").value.indexOf("@");
var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
```

TO this :

```
var name = document.getElementById("usr").value;
var email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value.indexOf("@");
var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an email directly with javascript for security reasons.
Suppose there is a feature in JavaScript to send email. Some malicious coder can write a script to send email to some address immediately when you visit their page. This will reveal your email address to some third party without your knowledge. They will start filling your mail box with lots of spam messages! However, there are alternatives as explained below. [link](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-email-form.phtml)

You can however open the user's mail client, to do so:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="sendMail(); return false">
...
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@abc.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
    ;
    window.location.href = link;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a mail directly from the browser, however you can use third party technologies like http://www.emailjs.com/ or create a .php file using php native mail function to send mail.

Below is the HTML, JS(Jquery AJAX) and PHP file that handles mail sending.

In this case the PHP script handles email verification, but you can also use HTML require or JS regex to check at the client side before sending a POST request to the server

### HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="contactform">
  <p>
   <label for="name">Your Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" class="input" >
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="email">Your Email</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" class="input">
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="message">Your Message</label>
   <textarea name="message" cols="88" rows="6" class="textarea" ></textarea>
  </p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send your message" class="button transition">
</form>
```

### JS (JQuery)

```
var $contactform = $('#contactform'),
    $success = 'Your message has been sent. Thank you!',
    $url = 'link to the hosted php script';

$contactform.submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
  })
  .done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    if (msg.success == true) {
      response = '<div class="success">' + $success + '</div>';
    }
    else {
      response = '<div class="error">' + msg.errors + '</div>';
    }

    // Hide any previous response text.
    $('.error, .success').remove();

    // Show response message.
    $contactform.prepend(response);
  })
  .fail(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

### PHP

```
<?php
  // Array to hold validation errors and response data.
  $errors = array();
  $data = array();

  // Validate the variables
  // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $msg = $_POST['message'];

  $nospace_name = trim($_POST['name']);
  $nospace_email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $nospace_message = trim($_POST['message']);

  // * wont work in FF w/ Allow-Credentials
  //if you dont need Allow-Credentials, * seems to work
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  //if you need cookies or login etc
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
  if ($this->getRequestMethod() == 'POST') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
    //if you need special headers
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with');
  }

  if (empty($nospace_name))
    $errors['name'] = "Name field is required.";

  if (empty($nospace_email))
    $errors['email'] = "Email field is required.";

  if (empty($nospace_message))
    $errors['message'] = "I would love to see your message.";

  if (!empty($nospace_email) && !preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$^", $nospace_email))
    $errors['bad_email'] = "Please enter a valid email address";


  // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
  if (!empty($errors)) {
    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
  }
  else {
    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

    // prepare message to be sent
    $to = "admin@example.com";
    $subject = "Website Contact Form: ".$name;

    $headers = "From: noreply@example.com\n"; // email address the generated message will be from. Recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email;

    // build the message
    $message = "Name: ".$name."\n\n";
    $message .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n";
    $message .= "Message: ".$msg;

    // send it
    $mailSent =  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // check if mail was sent successfully
    if (!$mailSent) {
      $errors['unknown_error'] = "Something went wrong...Please try again later";
      $data['success'] = false;
      $data['errors']  = $errors;
    }
    else {
      // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
      $data['success'] = true;
      $data['message'] = "Thank you for contacting me, I\'ll get back to you soon!";
    }

  }

  // return all our data to an AJAX call
  echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is don't do the form validation yourself, just let the browser do it. You will need to change the `input` type on your email input to `email`, and you will need to add the `required` attribute to every one you want to be required.

This way instead of using JavaScript you can just use standards-compliant HTML.

Then, since you can't send email directly from the browser, you need a third-party service to send the email, like for example [Formspree](https://formspree.io/). Alternatively you could write a server-side script for sending email, but it's much easier to just use a service.

**Here is the final code:**

```html
<form action="https://formspree.io/your.email.here@example.com">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="usr">Name*:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Name" name="message" required="required">
         </fieldset>
    
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address*:</label>
             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="required">
         </fieldset>
    
          <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label for="message">Message*:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" placeholder="Message" name="message" required="required"></textarea>
          </fieldset>
    
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

---

If you want to use Formspree and also have your visitors enter their company name, you can hack it by giving the company name field a name of "subject", which Formspree will forward to your email alongside the rest of the fields.